# Profit-Margins in the NK Model

Tags: macroeconomics, new-keynesian-economics, profits

How do profit margins vary over "business cycles" in the new Keynesian model?

I'm interested in responses of profit margins (actual price markups) to all three standard shocks in NK models: 
- TFP shocks
- Demand shocks
- Monetary policy shocks

As an example, here is what I came up with for TFP shocks, but I don't really trust my analysis on that.

If BC are driven by TFP shocks, a bust implies lower marginal productivity of labor. Assuming flexible wages, this implies a decrease in costs. Since there is an optimal markup that firms are targeting, this implies that firms want to decrease their prices. Those that cannot adjust prices now have higher markups, and *too high* markups (compared to their desired markups). Those that can adjust prices will achieve their desired markup - their markup is constant through a decrease in prices. So as a response, average markups increase when hit by a negative TFP shocks - but holding the negative TFP shock constant, over time markups will go back to $\epsilon$ as all firms have adjusted their prices.